# Basic Authentication in perl6 with Cro

Tags: basic-authentication, raku, cro

I am looking for a simple solution to protect my routes with the Basic Authentication mechanism with Cro. In my example I'd like to see a `401 Unauthorized` if you don't provide any credentials at all. If you provide wrong credentials I like to see a `403 Forbidden`

In my code example I never saw the `MyBasicAuth` middleware being called:

```
class MyUser does Cro::HTTP::Auth {
    has $.username;
}

subset LoggedInUser of MyUser where { .username.defined }

class MyBasicAuth does Cro::HTTP::Auth::Basic[MyUser, "username"] {
    method authenticate(Str $user, Str $pass --> Bool) {
        # No, don't actually do this!
        say "authentication called";
        my $success = $user eq 'admin' && $pass eq 'secret';
        forbidden without $success;
        return $success
    }
}

sub routes() is export {
    my %storage;
    route {
        before MyBasicAuth.new;
        post -> LoggedInUser $user, 'api' {
            request-body -> %json-object {
                my $uuid = UUID.new(:version(4));
                %storage{$uuid} = %json-object;
                created "api/$uuid", 'application/json', %json-object;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what I ment is that it seems not to be invoked. There is a `say "authentication called";`in the Middleware. (And it does not work as expected regarding the `401`and `403`)

Comment: works not on my box:
> curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://admin:secret@localhost/api -d '{"string": "hi"}'         
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

> curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46c2VjcmV0' http://localhost/api -d '{"string": "hi"}'             
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This structure:

```
route {
    before MyBasicAuth.new;
    post -> LoggedInUser $user, 'api' {
        ...
    }
}
```

Depends on the new `before`/`after` semantics in the upcoming Cro 0.8.0. In the current Cro release at the time of asking/writing - and those prior to it - `before` in a `route` block would apply only to routes that had already been matched. However, this was too late for middleware that was meant to impact what *would* match. The way to do this prior to Cro 0.8.0 is to either mount the middleware at server level, or to do something like this:

```
route {
    before MyBasicAuth.new;
    delegate <*> => route {
        post -> LoggedInUser $user, 'api' {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Which ensures that the middleware is applied before any route matching is considered. This isn't so pretty, thus the changes in the upcoming 0.8.0 (which also will introduce a `before-matched` that has the original `before` semantics).

Finally, `forbidden without $success;` is not going to work here. The `forbidden` sub is part of `Cro::HTTP::Router` and for use in route handlers, whereas middleware is not tied to the router (so you could decide to route requests in a different way, for example, without losing the ability to use all of the middleware). The contract of the `authenticate` method is that it returns a truthy value determining what should happen; it's not an appropriate place to try and force a different response code.

A failure to match an auth constraint like `LoggedInUser` will produce a 401. To rewrite that, add an `after` in the outermost `route` block to map it:

```
route {
    before MyBasicAuth.new;
    after { forbidden if response.status == 401; }
    delegate <*> => route {
        post -> LoggedInUser $user, 'api' {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my example I would only like to have `403` for failed logins, not for missing. It looks as your example would rewrite all `401` to `403`, right?

Comment: Add `&& request.has-header('authorization')` to the condition.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there is currently a bug in the cro release version which is already fixed in upstream on [github](https://github.com/croservices/cro-http). With the help of sena_kun from the #perl6 IRC channel we did use the current version of `cro-http`:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/croservices/cro-http.git
$ perl6 -Icro-http/lib example.p6
```

And then with `curl` i finally saw the "authentication called".
We've discovered another two little bugs:

The **first** one: When I invoked `curl -v -d '{"string":"hi"}' http://admin:secret@localhost:10000/api` I forgot to add `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

```
authentication called An operation first awaited:   in sub request-body at /home/martin/.workspace/voteimproved/cro-http/lib/Cro/HTTP/Router.pm6 (Cro::HTTP::Router) line 716   in block  at restapp/example.pl line 24 in block  at /home/martin/.workspace/voteimproved/cro-http/lib/Cro/HTTP/Router.pm6 (Cro::HTTP::Router) line 130

Died with the exception:
    Cannot unbox a type object (Nil) to int.
      in sub decode-payload-to-pairs at /home/martin/.workspace/voteimproved/cro-http/lib/Cro/HTTP/BodyParsers.pm6 (Cro::HTTP::BodyParsers) line 62
      in method parse at /home/martin/.workspace/voteimproved/cro-http/lib/Cro/HTTP/BodyParsers.pm6 (Cro::HTTP::BodyParsers) line 50
      in method body at /home/martin/.rakudobrew/moar-2018.08/install/share/perl6/site/sources/557D6C932894CB1ADE0F83C0596851F9212C2A67 (Cro::MessageWithBody) line 77
      in sub request-body at /home/martin/.workspace/voteimproved/cro-http/lib/Cro/HTTP/Router.pm6 (Cro::HTTP::Router) line 716
      in block  at restapp/example.pl line 24
      in block  at /home/martin/.workspace/voteimproved/cro-http/lib/Cro/HTTP/Router.pm6 (Cro::HTTP::Router) line 130
```

The **second** one was because of calling `forbidden` in this part:

```
class MyBasicAuth does Cro::HTTP::Auth::Basic[MyUser, "username"] {
    method authenticate(Str $user, Str $pass --> Bool) {
        say "authentication called";
        my $success = $user eq 'admin' && $pass eq 'secret';
        forbidden unless $success;
        return $success;
    } }
```

Which leads to this stacktrace:

```
authentication called
Can only use 'content' inside of a request handler
  in sub set-status at /home/martin/.workspace/voteimproved/cro-http/lib/Cro/HTTP/Router.pm6 (Cro::HTTP::Router) line 846
  in sub forbidden at /home/martin/.workspace/voteimproved/cro-http/lib/Cro/HTTP/Router.pm6 (Cro::HTTP::Router) line 823
  in method authenticate at restapp/example.pl line 15
  in method process-auth at /home/martin/.workspace/voteimproved/cro-http/lib/Cro/HTTP/Auth/Basic.pm6 (Cro::HTTP::Auth::Basic) line 26
  in block  at /home/martin/.workspace/voteimproved/cro-http/lib/Cro/HTTP/Auth/Basic.pm6 (Cro::HTTP::Auth::Basic) line 11
  in block  at /home/martin/.workspace/voteimproved/cro-http/lib/Cro/HTTP/Auth/Basic.pm6 (Cro::HTTP::Auth::Basic) line 8
  in block  at /home/martin/.workspace/voteimproved/cro-http/lib/Cro/HTTP/Internal.pm6 (Cro::HTTP::Internal) line 22
  in block  at /home/martin/.workspace/voteimproved/cro-http/lib/Cro/HTTP/RequestParser.pm6 (Cro::HTTP::RequestParser) line 109
  in block  at /home/martin/.workspace/voteimproved/cro-http/lib/Cro/HTTP/RequestParser.pm6 (Cro::HTTP::RequestParser) line 90
  in block  at /home/martin/.rakudobrew/moar-2018.08/install/share/perl6/site/sources/F048BB66854D2463798A39CC2B01D4CC1532F957 (Cro::TCP) line 53
```

I think this bugs will be fixed soon!